# Someone can explain this interval?

Tags: interval-arithmetic

I know that $ | a | < b$ it is a interval, where $ a $ and $ b $ is an generic expression, but how i can understand this? I want to transform this on the interval like this $ a < b < -a $ (or something like this) but i don't have idea how to make this.

Comment: Could you explain your question more clearly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of $|a|$ is $$|a|=\begin{cases}a,& a\geq0\\-a,&a<0\end{cases}$$

Therefore $|a|<b$ means that either

$$0\leq a<b$$

or

$$a<0, -a<b$$

which is the same as $-b<a<0$.

Since there is an **or** all valid cases are the union of both cases.

The union of $-b<a<0$ and $0\leq a<b$ is $$-b<a<b$$

Answer (score 0):

The inequality $$|a|<b$$ means that the absolute value of $a$ is strictly less than $b$; that is, $a$ is between $\pm b$.

Hence we have $$-b<a<b$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the definition of [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) the inequality $|a|<b$, is impossible for $b<0$ and, if $b\ge 0$ is equivalent to the couple of systems:

$$
\begin{cases}
a\ge 0\\
a<b 
\end{cases}
\quad \mbox{or}\quad
\begin{cases}
a< 0\\
-a<b 
\end{cases}
$$

can you solve from here?